# Minimum of $5^a x$ modulo $ 2^b$ for $1 \leq x < 2^c$

Tags: inequality, congruences, products

Given positive integers $a$, $b$, and $c$, and the function $f(x) = (5^a x)\ \%\ 2^b$, where $x\ \%\ y = x - y\lfloor \frac{x}{y} \rfloor$, what is the minimum of $f(x)$ the range $1 \leq x < 2^c$, with $x$ also integer?

Alternatively, given the inequality $(5^a x)\ \%\ 2^b < 2^d$, what is the minimum $x$ such that this is true?

This can be 'trivially' computed by trying all possible values for x, but I'm interested in cases where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all large such that it is not possible to try all possible values of $x$ in reasonable time. I have run a couple of examples with a program I wrote:

$a = 43, b = 97, c = 27: \mathrm{min}\ f(x) = 723839456393370823360$
$a = 44, b = 99, c = 27: \mathrm{min}\ f(x) = 31872086829510029993510$

I have looked for various combinations of product, congruence, and inequality, minimum on Google as well as here. I've tried Wolfram Alpha, which didn't give me anything useful (e.g. [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+5%5E43*x+modulo+2%5E97+on+1+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+16)).

At this point I'm not even sure there is a better solution than brute force $O(2^c)$. Even if there's no direct way to compute the result, I'd also accept an algorithm that takes less than linear time (e.g., $O(\sqrt{2^c})$ or $O(log(2^c))$).

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error I've discovered an algorithm that gives me the correct output for all the cases I've looked at, and that isn't brute force. Here's my Java code. I haven't been yet been able to prove correctness.

`BigInteger pow5 = BigInteger.valueOf(5).pow(28);
BigInteger pow2 = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(17);
BigInteger max = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(11);
BigInteger min3 = BigInteger.ZERO;
BigInteger pow5inv = pow5.modInverse(pow2);
BigInteger a = pow5.mod(pow2);
BigInteger b = pow2.mod(a);
outer: while (true) {
  while (b.compareTo(a) > 0) {
    b = b.mod(a);
  }
  while (a.compareTo(b) > 0) {
    // Note that this loop implements a = a.mod(b), but does so step by step.
    a = a.subtract(b);
    BigInteger orig = a.multiply(p5inv).mod(pow2);
    if (orig.compareTo(max) > 0) {
      break outer;
    }
    min = a;
  }
}`